# Why is my preview window in Xcode not displaying?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Whenever I try to see the preview for the following swiftUI code it says cannot preview this file landmarks crashed.

SwiftUI view file:

```
import SwiftUI

struct LandmarkRow: View {
    var landmark: Landmark
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("landmark.name")
        }
    }
}

struct LandmarkRow_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        LandmarkRow(landmark: landmarks[0])
    }
}
```

the landmarks file code is:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import CoreLocation

struct Landmark: Hashable, Codable {
    var id: Int
    var name: String
    var park: String
    var state: String
    var description: String

    private var imageName: String
    var image: Image {
        Image(imageName)
    }

    private var coordinates: Coordinates
    var locationCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D {
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(
            latitude: coordinates.latitude,
            longitude: coordinates.longitude)
    }

    struct Coordinates: Hashable, Codable {
        var latitude: Double
        var longitude: Double
    }
}
```

I am trying to follow an Apple tutorial and I can continue on it until I figure this out. I'll drop a link at the bottom of this question so you can view it more in depth, but its basically a tutorial to help devs learn how to use Xcode. It's supposed to create an app of various landmarks. The portion of code above is supposed to be for a list of the landmarks. All help is appreciated.

Tutorial: https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/building-lists-and-navigation

Comment: Where are you defining `landmarks`? (For example `let landmarks = [Landmark]()`)

Comment: Follow all the steps from the beginning.  You are supposed to have a swift file named 'Landmark' inside the Models folder.